# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' from Google translate API using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, google-translate

I have a dataframe with several columns including a text column, when I use the code from [here](https://medium.com/@prabhat.pathak/translate-list-and-pandas-data-frame-using-googletrans-library-in-python-ce3b8ddf4f12)
which is:

```
import pandas as pd
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator(service_urls=['translate.google.com',])

df["translate_result"] = df["to_translate"].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, src= "en", dest = "fr").text)
```

I get the error message :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I tried to update the translator function with service urls but it seems not the problem. What could be the issue here? thank you.

Comment: so i am currently trying another solution from here: https://pythonrepo.com/repo/nidhaloff-deep-translator-python-miscellaneous using #deep-translator-1.5.0

Comment: have you actually checked if all elements of your data column have a .text attribute that is not None?

Comment: yup, the same error appears when testing the solution from @Ricco D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error when I used googletrans v3 then I found an [open github issue](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/304) for this error. The suggested fix is to use
version `googletrans-4.0.0rc1-py3.9.egg-info`.

```
pip install 'googletrans==4.0.0rc1'
```

**translate.py:**

```
from googletrans import Translator
import pandas as pd

translator = Translator()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Spanish':['piso','cama']})
df['English'] = df['Spanish'].apply(translator.translate, src='es', dest='en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))
print(df)
```

I ran the [code from the link](https://medium.com/@prabhat.pathak/translate-list-and-pandas-data-frame-using-googletrans-library-in-python-ce3b8ddf4f12) you provided in the question and got the expected results.

Test done:
[image]

[image]

Comment: the solution and code provided by you produces an error message: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. any ideas why? thanks.

Comment: After testing in python 3.9 .py env the code you provides works. The comment above comes from using the jupyter notebook

Comment: Another [git issue](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/280) suggest to use `googletrans==3.1.0a0`. You can also try this one.

Comment: where can I find the rate limit of words to translate using this package? thank you.

Comment: @brygid it might be better to create a new post for your question regarding the limit of words since it is not related to the original question. Creating a new question will also open an opportunity for the community to contribute :)